# Merge two mysql tables and get result into datagrid in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have two MySQL tables,

tblloanRegistry

```
LoanID     EMPNumber     Date      Amount     Status
1          1111         2012-10-01  50000        0
2          2222         2012-10-10  10000        1
```

tblLoanAccount

```
ID     LoanID     Date     Payment     Interest     Total     Auto     Installment
1         1       2012-10-25  5000         0         5000        0           1
2         1       2012-11-01     0        100         100        1           0
3         1       2012-11-25  5000        100        5100        0           2
4         2       2012-11-25  1500         0         1500        0           1
```

Output for member 1111:

```
Date          Description     Principle    Interest      Balance
2012-10-25    Installment: 1     5000          0           45000
2012-11-01    Interest             0          100          45100
2012-11-25    Installment: 2     5000         100          40000
```

I tried the following, but it shows an error.

```
SELECT tblLoanAccount.Date, tblLoanAccount.Payment, tblLoanAccount.Interest, 
tblLoanAccount.Total, tblLoanAccount.Auto, tblLoanAccount.Installment FROM " &
"tblLoanAccount WHERE tblLoanAccount.EMPNumber=" & cmbEMPNumber.Text & " AND 
tblLoanAccount.LoanID = '1' AND tblLoanAccount.Total <> 0 ORDER BY tblLoanAccount.ID
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: From your description, it sounds like a VB.NET syntax error. Try putting the entire string on one line. In any case, please provide more details about this error: is it a syntax error, or a runtime error?

Comment: Also, be aware that best practice is to use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/B623F810-D871-49A5-B0F5-078CC3C34DB6(v=vs.100,d=lightweight).aspx) instead of concatenating strings into an SQL statement.

Comment: I have added the error above. I am very new to VB.NET. And if you can direct me to any tutorial it would be great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error because you haven't JOINed the tables.

Use this query for your expected answer. You should join both table then only you can get output.

```
SELECT tblLoanAccount.Date, tblLoanAccount.Payment, tblLoanAccount.Interest,
    tblLoanAccount.Total, tblLoanAccount.Auto, tblLoanAccount.Installment,     
    if(Installment = 0, 'Interest', concat('Installment : ', Installment)) as Description
FROM tblLoanAccount 
JOIN tblloanRegistry ON tblloanRegistry.LoanID = tblLoanAccount.LoanID
WHERE tblloanRegistry.EMPNumber= 1111 
    AND tblLoanAccount.LoanID = 1 
    AND tblLoanAccount.Total <> 0 
ORDER BY tblLoanAccount.ID
```

Your table schema is created at [this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e223/3). Kindly go through it.